# htaccess rewrite doesn't work

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect url's in my /joomla/ folder containing "rsform" to the same url but except for /joomla/ /formulieren/. However my tried .htaccess rewrite doesn't work. I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} rsform
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ http://watervriendengeleen.nl/joomla/ [L,R=301]
```

And other URL related rewrites like `Redirect /joomla/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=12&Itemid=99999 http://sitename.com/formulieren/index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=12&Itemid=99999` which didn't work either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what is the name of your .htaccess file?  also have you enabled mod_rewrite in apache (sudo a2enmod rewrite).

Comment: @Frank simply .htaccess (in the root, joomla itself also has .htaccess-files in /joomla/ and /formulieren/), yes.

Comment: @Frank additionally I'm using `RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !rsform
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !template
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !image
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !administrator

RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ http://sitename.com/joomla/ [L,R=301]` in the formulieren folder's .htaccess and that works fine

Comment: Do any rewrite rules work?  If not then your web server might not have URL Rewrite rules enabled thus ignoring .htaccess files.  Can you let us know what web server you are on?  Are you on linux or windows?

Comment: @Frank they do, however I just noticed that redirects on the /joomla/ folder get ignored. I'm using a CentOS6.0 Linux web server with Apache 2.2.27 - maybe Joomla is the blocking factor...

Comment: @Frank Made a mistake, that set-up is my usual server, currently on an old set-up. It's using linux and apache though and other redirects work.

Comment: Is the goal to redirect and change the /joomla/ to /formulieren/ ? if that is the case I think your rule needs to be in the base folder of your site.   But I am not 100% strong on writing these rules.  I think you would get a really quick answer on rewrite rules over at stack overflow.

Comment: If the problem is related to preventing indexing in search engines you'd be better of fixing the problem using a noindex or robot.txt solution. Generally pages so that they don't appear in search results is considered a band aid and bad for user experience and seo.

Comment: No only to redirect urls containing rsform to /formulieren/ because the forms-feature in the old site doesn't work anymore (some screw-up) and we're just weeks away from a new website so investing time in really fixing it isn't worth it.

Comment: As mentioned on SO, you need to match `rsform` against `%{QUERY_STRING}`. However, the solution on SO is eliminating the query string from the substitution - which I can't see as being correct - is it? Joomla itself uses a lot of mod_rewrite directives - so it's quite possible there is a conflict. However, this does have a bit of a bad code smell - what is the goal for doing this? (Btw, your question is perfectly on-topic here and should not be duplicated on more than one stack site - it would be moved by a moderator if deemed off-topic.)

Comment: @w3d Nope didn't work indeed. The bad code smell is correct, someone screwed up the form in the main site but we have a dev-clone with still working forms, only with data from 2013 so it can't fully take over the main site. Normally I would do this more clean by spending quite some time to just fix it but they are migrating to a new website in two weeks - so not worth the effort ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in the regex patter of a `RewriteRule` or a `Redirect`. You need to use mod_rewrite's `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} rsform
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ http://watervriendengeleen.nl/formulieren/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ah, allright. Unfortunately, your proposed code has the same result as mine, it gets ignored. :(

Comment: @RaimondvanMouche you sure your htaccess file is being read? Do you have all of the necessary modules loaded and options set to be able to use htaccess files and mod_rewrite?

Comment: how can I check the first? on the latter, yes, for example in the formulieren directory I have a .htaccess with `RewriteEngine on  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !rsform RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !template RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !image RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !administrator  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ http://watervriendengeleen.nl/joomla/ [L,R=301]` and that works perfectly fine. It's really weird.

Comment: @RaimondvanMouche if you have rewrite rules in subdirectories and you try to access the subdirectory, any mod_rewrite rules in parent directories are completely ignored

Comment: Ah that's good to know. Unfortunatly, I tried your suggested rewrites in both the root .htaccess and the /joomla/'s .htaccess to no avail...

Comment: @RaimondvanMouche Don't know what your problem is, [it works perfectly fine in my blank htaccess file](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a7lT1.png).

Comment: Hmm, only thing I can think of myself is Joomla blocking the rewrite. Is there any way to overrule this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following mod_rewrite directives should do what you require, however, whether they do *anything at all* may be dependent on your configuration.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} rsform
RewriteRule ^joomla/(.+)$ http://watervriendengeleen.nl/formulieren/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects all requests for files in your `/joomla/` subfolder, containing the string "rsform" anywhere in the *query string* (as suggested by your example) to the same URL in the `/formulieren/` subfolder. The query string is also copied across to the substituted URL.

However, I do wonder whether you should be *redirecting* here, as it may be more preferable to internally rewrite the request if possible? ie. remove the `R=301` flag. (But this may or may not work for you?)